# How to add a strike through for each character deleted pressing backspace or del button

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce

I got this weird requirement and Im not sure how to achieve it.

When we press the backspace button we shouldnt delete the content but instead add a strike through over the previous text.

What i tried is this

```
ed.on('keydown', function( args,e ) {
                        if(evt.keyCode == 8){
                            $('#p').wrap('<strike>')
                        }
                    });
```

But the problem i face is that the whole `<p>` tag get a strike. Is there a way to add the `<strike>` to each character deleted on clicking the backspace button using jquery/javascript ?

**Note:** Im using a TincyMCE plugin for the text editor

Comment: for that you will need to wrap the character itself meaning you need to add a strike inside of the `p` element, not surrounding it

Comment: Yeah .. i understood that .. but how do i achieve it .. as in each character I delete , how do i add a strike through ?